# prestashop currency block and language block is not displaying properly

Tags: module, prestashop-1.5

I need to implement currency block as well as language block in my prestashop shop v1.5.6.1.I have implemented these modules in advance footer section.language block is visible but i cant able to change the language by using dropdown.Currency block module is not dislaying at all in front end.

Comment: have you enabled multiple currencies? and what javascript error you got while you change the language dropdown?

Comment: I am getting the dropdown as a list.i need to implement it as a combo box.it would be helpful if i can get a link to download the currency block module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line in your blockcurrencies.php file

```
    public function hookdisplayFooter($params){
    if ($this->_prepareHook($params))
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockcurrenciesfooter.tpl');       
}
```

add a blockcurrenciesfooter.tpl in your module folder.

add this code in blockcurrenciesfooter.tpl

```
<form id="setCurrency" action="{$request_uri}" method="post">
    <div class="change_currency"><span>Choose Currency</span><br/> 
        <select class="change_currency"> 
            {foreach from=$currencies key=k item=f_currency} 
            <option value="{$f_currency.id_currency}">
                {$f_currency.sign} {$f_currency.name}
            </option> 
            {/foreach} 
        </select> 
    </div> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.change_currency').change(function(){
javascript:setCurrency($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Hook "Currency block" module to displayFooter

Comment: where i need to implement this code?If it is in blockcurrencies.tpl ,kindly mention exactly where i need to add this code.

Comment: <form id="setCurrency" action="{$request_uri}" method="post">
<div class="change_currency">
<span>Choose Currency</span><br/>
<select>
{foreach from=$currencies key=k item=f_currency}
<option onclick="javascript:setCurrency({$f_currency.id_currency});" value="{$f_currency.id_currency}">{$f_currency.sign} {$f_currency.name}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
</div>
</form>

Comment: make sure that you have assigned the $request_uri,$currencies for the smarty file.

Comment: Can u please explain how to assign  $request_uri,$currencies for the smarty file?I have implemented the above form in my footer section,just i am getting the dropdown with a single data as {$f_currency.sign} {$f_currency.name}.its not retrieving the currency value.

Comment: I have implemented the code.Now i can able to change the currency of my site by selecting dropdown value at first time only.After first selection currency changed for the products in my site but in dropdown it remains same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42402/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-shaik-rilwan)

Comment: change this line <option value="{$f_currency.id_currency}" {if $blockcurrencies_sign == $f_currency.sign}selected="selected"{/if}>{$f_currency.sign} {$f_currency.name}</option>

Answer (score 0):

I have made block language module to work by adding languages downloaded from [Translation](http://www.prestashop.com/en/translations) and upload it into my **prestashop** through

> **admin->localization->languages**

Now its working fine.

Comment: you can import from the "Import a localization pack" in         admin->localization->localization and select package and import it